# How can I encode/decode to base64?

Tags: php, base64, httpclient, encode

I want to encode/decode my Image with base64:

```
  $imageEncoded = base64_encode($image);
  $imageDecoded = imagecreatefromstring(base64_decode($imageEncoded));
```

But it is not correctly decoded

Comment: [PHP parse/syntax errors; and how to solve them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18050071/php-parse-syntax-errors-and-how-to-solve-them)

Comment: Provide the full error message (including the part which states at which line the error occurs, when you do that, make sure to let us know which line this refers to.)

Comment: And you copied the code and is therefor **exactly** like this as shown in your question and does not lack a `;` in the line above `$imageFromString = imagecreatefromstring(base64_decode($imageEncoded));`?

Comment: The mentioned duplicate is not just about quotes.

Comment: And the code as currently shown above, does not throw any _parse_ errors at all, as https://3v4l.org/pMv4E proves.

Comment: Then why are you showing us this code, and say it gave you that specific error - when it actually doesn’t?

Comment: I feel like you are not being completely honest. Suddenly the error changes? And you changed nothing? For same inputs it should generate same outputs (including same errors) unless youre programming a random number generator. Downvoting, because this is a different question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to use `imagecreatefromstring` in your code. You can `encode/decode` with php `base64` functions.

```
$imageEncoded = base64_encode($your_image);
$imageDecoded = base64_decode($imageEncoded);
```

Comment: But how can I get now the image size?

Comment: How can I create the resampled image without getimagesizefromstring?

Comment: `$imageDecoded` should be an image already. All the image info, including image size should be already encoded in base64_encode and can be restored with base64_decode. Can you please try to use `$imageDecoded` as your image at where you want to display.